# How can i use a tags input or editext for android

Tags: android, android-edittext, tags, addition

Hello I'm new developing in Android,  I want to insert in a edittext a Word and make it like a tag with the space or enter key I was looking for it a lot but could not find an answer.

I want to make something like this:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were approaching this problem, I would first look into `TextWatcher` (or the `String.split()` method) and `SpannableString`.

"Tags" are normally separated manually by a space or a comma, so you could use `String[] words = sentence.split(",");` to split by commas, and then use a `for` loop to set a `BackgroundColorSpan` of light blue, a `ForegroundColorSpan` of deep blue, an `ImageSpan` for the cross and a `ClickableSpan` for links.

To update it more dynamically would require using `TextWatcher`.